# Change button background to clicked

Tags: android, button, background

When you press on a button in Android it changes color. I want it to stay like that. I mean i want something like this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             btn.setBackGroundColor(R.drawable.clicked /*clicked style*/ );
         }
     });
```

example:

[image]

This is a pressed on button. I want it to stay like that after i stop pressing it. Is there a easy way like that:

android.R.drawable.btn_default //this is the default button style, i want the pressed one :D

Comment: have a look at this blog http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/ this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

In your java code write `button.setPressed(true);`.It will set button in pressed mode. You can change the parameter to true and false when you want to set it pressed and unpressed...

Answer (score 1):

So you want it to start non-pressed and then stay pressed after being clicked one?
Try using an OnTouchListener instead adding `btn.setPressed(true);`:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                btn.setPressed(true);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: When i use setPressed in some other method then buttons onClick, It works. But it doesn't work when i use it in onClick. I think it automatically change setPressed to false when onClick event finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using selector:

Define selector.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
              android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
    </selector>
```

and set background of the button to `android:background="@drawable/selector"` then in the code on the click event of the button set `btn.setpressed(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way either put image as dark when press or color

drawable/selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttondark"/>
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/buttondark" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" /> 
</selector>
```

inside on-create method write

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
```

Comment: It seems to be a good solution. But in selector.xml it gives errors: "Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/buttondark')" and " Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@drawable/button')."

Comment: just because image s not there on your resource folder put the image or color in place of buttondark

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of the StateSelector images

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

You can set diferent resources for the diferent states of your button/view. This example set different colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@color/branded_content_pressed_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/branded_content_pressed_color" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/branded_content_background_color"/>
</selector>
```

Then you can set the selector normally

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
```